# Python: Gzip-package does not recognize file as gzip-file

Tags: python, gzip

I have a file, which has a gzip file in it. So after I extracted the header via python, I try to decompress the data from the gzip file. This is my code:

```
import binascii
import gzip

[...]

with open(self.filepath,'rb') as file:
    [...]
    gz = file.read()
    assert binascii.hexlify(gz[0:3]) == b"1f8b08"
    x = gzip.decompress(gz)
```

While this works for some files, it does not for others and I absolutely dont know why! The error I get is:

```
OSError: Not a gzipped file (b'\x03\x00')
```

But as you can see, I assert beforehand to make sure it is the correct magic number. Even when I dump `gz` into a real file, I can open it with 7zip. So:

1. When the assert is true, and the magic number of this is b"1f8b08", then why does the gzip package think otherwise and tells me it is b"0300" for this file?
2. I looked into the script of the gzip package. The error flies at

```
if magic != b'\037\213':
    raise OSError('Not a gzipped file (%r)' % magic)
```

Why does the gzip package want **this** magic number? I read everywhere it is the one I use?

I hope, you guys can help me and tell me where my thinking mistake is. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`b'\037\213'` is in octal, and is exactly the same thing as `b'\x1f\x8b'` in hexadecimal.